# Why my seedlings died within few hours?

Tags: seedlings, germination

I got seed and pot to grow carrots. They sprouted little tiny plants. As they are in windowsill I put them out in sun for few hours. It was fine but today after few hours they tried up and seem burnt? I do water them everyday but why it happened.

Will they grow again or I will need to put more seed?

[image]

Comment: The soil in the photo looks very dry.

Comment: @blacksmith37 the instruction said to spray the soil so I use spray. I thought watering it will damage/overflow the seed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the specific light requirements of carrots, but seedlings are usually too delicate for full sun. Would usually need to wait until they are more established before giving them all the light the adult plant needs. Seeding again sounds like a good idea.

I noticed that is a metal pot, likely without drainage holes. This will be difficult to water, as water can accumulate inside without having anywhere to drain away into when the soil has absorbed all it can. I suggest using that as a cover pot, putting a plastic pot with drainage holes inside.

Comment: If carrot seed is (as is usual, they transplant poorly) planted in the garden, full sun is fine for the seedlings. Like most plants, if they have been getting only windowsill levels of light, some hardening-off (short exposures of longer and longer times) will be required to take full sun. Those also look very dry.

Comment: There was a hole at the bottom the size of a fingertip, I put a stone on it (read somewhere u need to do it otherwise everything you water in the soil will wash away). so once it has died, the seed cannot produce a seedling? what is rule of thumb for sunshine?